# Angular NGRX - updating related data

Tags: angular, ngrx

Say I have an entity `Tag`. This entity is recursive, meaning a `Tag` can have sub-`Tag`(s)

```
Tag {
  id: string,
  childrenIds: string[]
}
```

This entity is used for an `EntityState<Tag>`, so that it is normalized.
I'm using a `MatTree` to display this hierarchical structure, and when a `Tag` is created as another `Tag`'s child, I fire an event:

```
emitTagCreated(parentId: string, newTagId: string): void {
   this.tagCreated.emit({ parentId, newTagId })
}
```

This event is then caught by the parent `Component`, which invokes `Store.dispatch()`

Two things should happen:

1. the *new* `Tag` is inserted in the `Store`
2. the *parent* `Tag` has its `childrenIds` array property updated, pushing the new `Tag`'s id

Question time:
should I `dispatch()` a single `Action` passing a composite payload and centralizing this inside a `Reducer`'s switch branch, or should I `dispatch()` two `Action`s: one for the `Tag` creation, and one for the `Tag` update and handle those as different `Reducer`'s operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One dispatch is better here imho, this will make things more clear.

Also when you would create 2 actions, you or a team member can forget to fire the second action in a different scenario, resulting in a bad state.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think there is an even better approach?

Comment: For example: should the Tag object be created inside the Reducer or in the Component (so to have a cleaner Reducer)? I have many doubts like this one

Comment: I like to put this logic inside the action creator, if I need something from state I usually do it inside the reducer- https://blog.angularindepth.com/lets-have-a-chat-about-actions-and-action-creators-within-ngrx-41277ecc739d

Comment: Thanks. Another question: being that I need to fire an entityAdapter.updateOne() to update the parent.childrenIds array, I also need to get this array from the Store. Is it a good approach to do that like parentTag = store.entities[parentId] in the Reducer? So the sequence would be adding the new Tag, getting the parent Tag, updating the parent Tag. But maybe the parent get/update can be somehow simplified

Comment: Yea, that's fine :)

Comment: Awesome! Well if you are on the ngrx/store Gitter you'll see my messages often I think :P

Comment: You can find me there :)